# Modify JSON string comparing another JSON string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to modify below JSON string #1  with the given information from JSON string #2 with ruby. Output should be like below string#3 (one key:value added and one key:value updated from String #2). After searching a lot I don't find any similar solution If anybody know please help

Input String#1

```
{   "AC01": { "state": [ {"old": "112", "new": "100"} ],
              "temp": [{"old": "12","new": "200" }] },
    "AC02": { "state": [ {"old": "12","new": "120"}],
              "temp": [ {"old": "12","new": "220"}]}
}
```

Input String#2

```
{   "AC01": { "state": [ { "new": "200", "time": "12212" } ] }
}
```

output Json string should be like this:
String #3

```
{   "AC01": { "state": [ {"old": "100", "new": "200","time": "12212"} ],
              "temp": [{"old": "12","new": "200" }] },
    "AC02": { "state": [ {"old": "12","new": "120"}],
              "temp": [ {"old": "12","new": "220"}]}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [deep_merge gem](https://github.com/danielsdeleo/deep_merge). Something like this:

```
js1 = '{   "AC01": { "state": [ {"old": "112", "new": "100"} ],
              "temp": [{"old": "12","new": "200" }] },
           "AC02": { "state": [ {"old": "12","new": "120"}],
              "temp": [ {"old": "12","new": "220"}]}
}'
js2 = '{   "AC01": { "state": [ { "new": "200", "time": "12212" } ] } }'

require 'json'
require 'deep_merge'

obj1 = JSON.parse(js1)
obj2 = JSON.parse(js2)
p obj1.deep_merge(obj2, {:merge_hash_arrays => true}).to_json
```

Result is:

```
{
    "AC01": {
        "state": [{"old": "112","new": "100","time": "12212"}],
        "temp": [{"old": "12","new": "200"}]
    },
    "AC02": {
        "state": [{"old": "12","new": "120"}],
        "temp": [{ "old": "12","new": "220" }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Also, if you are using Rails, you already have deep_merge and don't need the extra gem.

Comment: thank you very much Mr Yevgeniy Anfilofyev, here I wanted 2 things from string#2 1) addition 2) modify previous value. #1 is done . but #2 is not complete. I need this ---> "AC01": { "state": [ {"old": "100", "new": "200","time": "12212"} (here "old" value "100" come from string#1 "new" value, exchange position, other things are ok) can you please tell me how can I do it

Comment: I see. What should you do in this case is just change obj1 and obj2 in `... obj1.deep_merge(obj2 ...`. But if you want to use any other algorytm ... well it would be another story ;)